# Bits visualization using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, bit, qpainter

I'm writing a program that can display file in bit view. Bits are visualized as filled and empty circles. Orogram allows to group bits by period, select bits, highlight columns and rows etc. I'm using Qt6 and c++.

I'm trying to use paintEvent + QPainter but when I draw ~32k bits main window started to freeze and crushes. How can I draw for example 1MB file without freezes?

Bits should be displayed like this( columns size can be changed).[image]

This is code I have so far. Just simple visualization and bit generating. Generated 10K bits and main window is freezing while scrolling.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>
#include <QToolTip>
#include <QDebug>

class BitItem : public QGraphicsEllipseItem
{
public:
    BitItem(int index, int radius, QGraphicsItem* parent = nullptr) : QGraphicsEllipseItem(parent), index_(index)
    {
        setRect(0, 0, radius, radius);
    }

    void SetValue(int value)
    {
        value_ = value;
        update();
    }

    int GetValue() const noexcept
    {
        return value_;
    }

protected:
    void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget = nullptr) override
    {
        painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        QBrush brush(Qt::SolidPattern);

        if (value_)
            brush.setColor(Qt::black);
        else
            brush.setColor(Qt::white);

        painter->setBrush(brush);
        painter->drawEllipse(rect());
    }
private:
    unsigned index_{0};
    bool value_{false};
};

class BitsView : public QGraphicsView
{
public:

    BitsView(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QGraphicsView(parent)
    {
        QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
        setScene(scene);
        GenerateBits(scene);
        setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    }

    void GenerateBits(QGraphicsScene* scene) // debug function 
    {
       srand(time(nullptr));
     
        for (int i = 0; i < BITS_COUNT_; ++i)
        {
            int row = i / COLUMN_SIZE_;
            int column = i % COLUMN_SIZE_;

            int x = column * (RADIUS_ + RADIUS_);
            int y = row * (RADIUS_ + SPACING_);

            BitItem* bit = new BitItem(i, RADIUS_);
            bit->SetValue(rand() % 2);
            bit->setPos(x, y);
            scene->addItem(bit);
        }
    }

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) override
    {
        QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);
        UpdateBitPositions();
    }

private:
    unsigned SPACING_{ 2 };
    unsigned BITS_COUNT_{ 10000 };
    unsigned COLUMN_SIZE_{ 64 };
    unsigned RADIUS_{ 10 };

    void UpdateBitPositions() 
    {
        QGraphicsScene* scene = this->scene();
        if (!scene)
            return;

        int row{ 0 }, column{0};
        for (QGraphicsItem* item : scene->items())
        {
            item->setPos(column * (RADIUS_ + SPACING_), row * (RADIUS_ + SPACING_));

            ++column;
            if (column == COLUMN_SIZE_)
            {
                column = 0;
                ++row;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    BitsView bits_view;
    bits_view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Show your code if you want someone to answer.

Comment: Essentially, a low-effectiveness tool for such task. You're stalling GUI thread. How you even fit that many on scrern? Average screen is close to 2 million pixels. For such tasks you need off-screen drawing or use of some acceleration,

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie or some kind of segmentation so you're only rendering the part of the data you are requiring for the current page.

Comment: Use QGraphicsView instead of QPainter.

Comment: Can you provide a window/screen capture image that shows us the 'look' you're trying to achieve with your GUI?

Comment: @MarkRansom yeah, that too. Often known as tiling when we talk about 2D image.  It was implied he tried to draw them in paint event. Tiling and offscreen rendering can be combined for case when the displayed data is static, we can create image (or a tiled array of such) for future use.

Comment: Could it be done with Qt or there is better instrument for this task?

Comment: I think if it can be realized like "Model-View-ViewModel" where I load bitt to some container , bind it with widget and so on?

Comment: You have not written anything about how you compile your application but it is very important for your question. On my computer, I start seeing (very) small performance issues with 20k bits in debug but it works just fine with 500k bits in release and I am sure my computer could take more of a beating before starting to struggle. This big a difference is not an anomaly BTW. Hope the suggestion helps!

Comment: Didn't work much with QT and didn't even expect such performance difference.  Thanks.

Comment: @rooltex: Can I take it your issue is solved just by compiling in Release? BTW, this difference is not a specificity of Qt. Every time an iterator is involved (which is the case here), be it in Qt or in the STL, a ton of extra checks take place in debug, such as making sure you compare iterators from the same container.

Comment: @Atmo: No, the issue hasn't solved yet.  Release build hasn't helped. I still need open large amount of bits and be able to set column size. I've found out how to paginate data of large file and display it but when period is large( column size is >10k ) it is steel freezing.  Probably I should try another approach to solve this task.